# In symbol table how to mark variable out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, symbol-table

I am writing a toy compiler, which compile a c/c++ like language to c++.
I am using bison, but in this structure is hard to handle when variable became out of scope.

In the source lanugage in the whole main function there can be only one variable with the same name, it is good, but there is a problem what I cannot solve.

I cannot make c++ code like this, because c++ compiler throw semantical error:
'var' was not declared in this scope.

```
    int main()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            int var = 4;
        }
        if (true)
        {
            var = 5;
        }
    }
```

The source language has while, if and if/else statements.
I have to throw semantical error if a declared variable is assinged in out of scope.
For example:

This should be semantical error, so I cannot generetad this code:

```
int main()
{
    while(0)
    {
        int var = 1;
    }

    if (1)
    {
        var = 2;
    }
}
```

This also have to be semantical error:

```
int main()
{
    if (0)
    {
        int var = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (1)
        {
            var = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is allowed, I can generate this code:

```
int main()
{
    if (0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        int var = 1;
        if (1)
        {
            while (0)
            {
                while (0)
                {
                    var = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried lot of things, but I cannot solve when there is nested if, if/else or while.

I read tons of tutorials about symbol table, but none of them can explain properly how to manage a variable if it is become out of scope.

If you familiar with this topic and with bison, please do not just give me hints, like "use stack, and mark a variable if it become out of scope". I found lot of article about it.
Instead of please give me pseudocode or concrate implementation sketch.

I think it cannot be so much difficult, because in the whole main function there can be one variable with the same name as I wrote.

Symbol table:

```
struct SymbolType
{
    int lineNumber;
    std::string identifier;
    int identifierValue;
    Type type;
    int functionArgumentNumber;
    Type functionReturnType;
    Type markType;
    bool outOfScope;
};

    class Symbol
    {
        public:
            void AddVariable(int _lineNumber, std::string _identifier, int _identifierValue, Type _type, int _functionArgumentNumber, Type _functionReturnType, Type _markType, bool _outOfScope);
            void AddMarker(int _lineNumber, std::string _scopeName, Type _markType);
            bool FindVariable(std::string _identifier);
            int FindVariableValue(std::string _identifier);
            void Remove();
            void Print();
            std::vector<SymbolType> symbolTable;

        private:
            int lineNumber;
            std::string identifier;
            int identifierValue;
            Type type;
            int functionArgumentNumber;
            Type functionReturnType;
            Type markType;
            bool outOfScope;
    };
```

Comment: i never wrote a compiler, but I guess I'd build a stack to keep track of what is in scope and what not

Comment: Could you please post your symbol table data structure? Generally, the symbol table should be a recursive structure - you would have a top-level/global symbol table, and individual symbol tables for each function and (in case where they are supported) each nested block scope within a function (e.g., if an `if()` or `for()` statement have a local scope, you would have a scope for each of those). You would traverse backwards through the scopes up towards the global scope when searching for a symbol.

Comment: About marking out of scope – I'd just remove the variable from the symbol table – unless you want to disallow e.g. `if(1) { int var = 10; } /* ... */ if(1) { long var = 12; }`, i.e. reusing a variable name for a new one after the other one already went out of scope.

Comment: @molbdnilo it is not about name collision, it's about using variable out of scope.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA I provided it. I store symbolTable in a vector.

Comment: @Aconcagua No, I want just make a semantic error when the user wants to use the declared variable out of scope, I provided examples, does it help?

Comment: I wouldn't make a difference if a variable hasn't ever been declared or has gone out of scope – if it is not found in the symbol table I'd just print an error like *'does not exist'*.

Comment: Pretty skeptical about very first example, by the way: Do you really want to allow to hide a variable that already *is* in scope? In complex functions it can get pretty difficult to spot which variable you are now actually changing. Maybe yet acceptable for global vs. function scope (C, C++), but within a function I don't recommend to.

Comment: As an aside, there seems to be a copy-paste problem in the `Symbol` class definition with the line `void Removjelenleg` apparently being garbled or incomplete. It doesn't seem especially relevant to the problem at hand, but it is a bit confusing. You might want to fix it for clarity's sake.

Comment: @Aconcagua So sorry, the very first exapmle was wrong, I edited.

Comment: The symbol table code is a bit confusing to me. You have a `struct` type describing the symbols, followed by a `class` whose private members are the same as those of the `struct` type; the class *also* contains a public `vector` of the structure type. Is `Symbol` supposed to be the class for the symbols, or the class for the symbol _table_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now let's assume the following: While you are in a nested scope you cannot add a variable to a parent scope. So we can work e.g. with a stack like structure (push/pop at the end only suffices, but with read access to all entries – the latter requirement disqualifying `std::stack`, so we'd operate e.g. on `std::vector` instead).

1. Encountering the declaration of a new variable:
   Run up the entire stack to see if that variable exists already. If so, issue an error (*'duplicate declaration/definition'*).
2. Encountering accessing a variable: Run up the entire stack to see if that variable exists; if not, issue an error (*'not declared/defined'* – I wouldn't differentiate between the variable not having been defined ever or having left the scope).
3. On leaving a scope, run up the stack and remove any variable that resides in that scope.

To be able to do 3. you have (at least) two options:

1. With every stack entry provide an identifier for the respective scope, could be simple counter. Then delete all those variables that have the same counter value. If you fear the counter might overflow, then reduce it by 1 as well (then it would always represent current scope depths).
2. Have a sentinel type – that one would be pushed to the stack on opening a new scope, compare unequal to any variable name, and on leaving a scope you'd delete all variables until you encounter the sentinel – and the sentinel itself.

This processing makes your `outOfScope` member obsolete.

Your `addVariable` function takes too many parameters, by the way – why should a variable need a return type, for instance???

I recommend adding multiple functions for every specific semantic type your language might provide (`addVariable`, `addFunction`, ...). Each function accepts what actually is necessary to be configurable and sets the rest to appropriate defaults (e.g. `Type` to `Function` within `addFunction`).

*Edit – processing the example from your comment:*

```
while(condition)
{   // opens a new scope:
    // either place a sentinel or increment the counter (scope depth)

    int var = 1; // push an entry onto the stack
                 // (with current counter value, if not using sentinels)

    if (true)
    {   // again a new scope, see above

        var = 2; // finds 'var' on the stack, so fine

    }   // closes a scope:
        // either you find immediately the sentinel, pop it from the stack
        // and are done
        //
        // or you discover 'var' having a counter value less than current
        // counter so you are done as well

}   // closing next scope:
    // either you find 'var', pop it from the stack, then the sentinel,
    // pop it as well and are done
    //
    // or you discover 'var' having same counter value as current one,
    // so pop it, then next variable has lower counter value again or the
    // stack is empty, thus you decrement the counter and are done again
```

Comment: Thank you, seems good, but in bison I have to figure out how to handle if I leave a nested scope.
Lets say:
`while(condition)
{
    int var = 1;
    if (true)
    {
        var = 2;
    }
}`

I still do not know how to pop variable after end of while not before if started.

Comment: I believe what @Aconagua is suggesting is a stack of symbol tables - something like a `std::vector<Symbol>` and using `.push_back()` and `.pop_back()` to enforce stack discipline. The reason you would use a `std::vector<>` rather than a `std::stack<>` is because you'll want to traverse this stack when searching up the chain of scopes.

Comment: I doubt it will help much, as it is written in Python rather than C++ and so wouldn't be an exact analogue, but my own compiler project's [`Symbol`](https://github.com/Schol-R-LEA/Suntiger-Algol/blob/master/src/Symbol.py) and [`SymbolTable`](https://github.com/Schol-R-LEA/Suntiger-Algol/blob/master/src/SymbolTable.py) classes might be worth reviewing.

Comment: Rather than a stack of symbols, a common way to handle this is to have a symbol table per scope, and each of those keeps a pointer to its parent scope.  The global scope wouldn't have a parent.  While compiling, you have a pointer to the current scope.  New symbols go in the current scope.  To look up a symbol, you begin looking in the current scope.  If it's not there, you (recursively or iteratively) search the parent scope if there is one.  If you retain the entire tree, you can generate comprehensive debug metadata.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy But that's what I'm doing. The stack is just another form of data representation, placing all scopes into linear array one after another instead of having a two-dimenstional array (vector of vectors) – which is possible as there's no way to add a new variable to a higher scope as long as we are yet in a deeper one...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, there is similarity, which is why I wrote a comment rather than another answer.  The biggest distinction is tree versus stack.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy In the end its just the data structure, the *algorithm* remains the same ;) I could propose double indexing, hashtable for quick lookup, vector of vectors of iterators into (well, would need to be rebuild on re-hashing, but that shouldn't occur too often – alternatively std::map with O(log(n)) lookup and stable iterators) – how huge would a compilation unit need to be to effectively profit from???